# Using Jquery, how do I find pixel value of a property's percentage and add it to a different property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and I'm having some trouble with it.

```
.pageimage {
  width:80%;
  height:60%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#0FF;
  position:absolute;
  left:;
  top:20%;
}
```

Using jquery, I'm trying to find the pixel value of 'top', subtract `50%` from that value, and then place that value on the 'left' property.

Also, does anyone know how to rerun this script after the browser window has been resized?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "subtract 50% from that value"? Is it `top/2` or `calc(top - 50%)`?

Comment: If you found any of the submitted answers useful, please remember to accept one by clicking the tick mark next to it. This will help indicate the best/most useful solution provided to your poblem to future visitors. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this, using the `.css()` method creatively. If you get the `.css("top")` of an element, it is returned in `px`, so you have to `replace("px","")` to be able to use the numeric value, then divide by 2, then add the `"px"` at the end again.

Wrap this up in a function and call it when your page loads. Then add a `$window.resize()` handler to run the function every time the window is resized after it's loaded.

Here's a full example:

```js
function updatePageImageLeft() {
  var calculatedLeft = $(".pageimage").css("top").replace("px", "") / 2 + "px";
  // console.log(calculatedLeft);
  $(".pageimage").css("left", calculatedLeft);
}

// Called when the page loads
updatePageImageLeft();

// Page has been resized, call it again
$(window).resize(function() {
  updatePageImageLeft();
});
```

```css
.pageimage {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #0FF;
  position: absolute;
  /*left: ;*/
  top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageimage"></div>
```

**Note:** You might also want looking into the [CSS `calc()` function](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp), as it could help you avoid writing any Javascript/jQuery code in the first place (especially if you combine it with CSS custom properties).

Answer (score 0):

To get the Value of "top" you can youse the function css.

```
var top = $(".pageimage").css("top");
$(".pageimage").css("left",parseInt(top)* 0.5);
```

to rerun the script after the window has been resized use:

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
    //place Code here
    }
```

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u3jz4kL/5/)

**Edit**
use parseInt to get the int-Value of top